# Delphi, copying folder in iOS

Tags: delphi

I am using RAD Studio xe6 and I am trying to copy a folder into a user defined location, without success until now.

What I am trying is

```
_system(PAnsiChar('cp -r '+folder1Path+' '+folder2path+'/'));
```

and the response of PAServer is something between the lines of

'c: command not found'

Is there a good way of achieving what I am after in iOS?

Comment: 1) Don't use `_system`. Use the Delphi IOUtils functions instead, where you're not using platform specific code. 2) Don't concatenate path information yourself. Use the Delphi IOUtils (specifically TPath.Combine) to do it correctly cross platform. 3) It's hard for us to say what the problem is, because you've not provided the folder locations or an actual error message. ("something between the lines of <some guess at the message>" is not useful).

Comment: Got it, i just saw the documentation of IOUtils and it is indeed what I want.

Comment: I wonder if IOUtils has a good directory copy routine. On windows I like SHFileOperation. I don't know whether or not iOS offers a good function for this. It would be nice to call the system native function for this task. Perhaps as covered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119940/ios-copy-directories-including-subdirectories

Comment: FWIW: To me it looks like an ANSI vs. Unicode issue: The `'cp -r...'` seems to be interpreted as `'c'#0'p'#o...`. So I suspect the `PAnsiChar` cast.

Comment: @KenWhite if you could make your comment into an answer so I can accept it would be great, since that was what I did to fix my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use _system use :  System.IOUtils.TDirectory.GetFiles