# ios - Move folders from Library folder to Documents folder

Tags: ios, iphone

How can move folder from one location to another location.
I have a folder inside Library/data, i need to move to  Documents/data. Is it possible ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS copy directories including subdirectories](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119940/ios-copy-directories-including-subdirectories)

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *pathDirectory= NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *toPath = [[pathSong objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"toFolderName"];
```

Use following line if you want to move a file from in document directory

```
NSString *fromPath=[[pathSong objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"fromFolderName"];
```

if you want to move from bundle then use following

```
NSString *frompath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"fileName" ofType:@"fileType"];

NSError *Error;
```

// If you want to add any subPath to destination folder add else commit following line

```
 NSString *toPath = [[pathSong objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"toSub"];
```

//DELETE THE FILE AT THE LOCATION YOU'RE COPYING TO

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
[fileManager removeItemAtPath:toPath error:NULL];

if([[NSFileManager defaultManager]copyItemAtPath:from toPath:toPath error:&Error]==NO){
 // do somthing on succes if you want
}
```

Comment: Hi @MOHAMMAD, is there any way to move entire folder from Bundle to Documents ?.